# How To Make A variable with value appear once on the url php

Tags: php, html, url, hyperlink, query-string

I have a code here which works and what it does is to add a variable and value to the current url.
what i did was to get the current url using

**PHP**

```
function c_url() {
   $cUrl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $vUrl = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cUrl);

   return $vUrl;
}
```

And then when i click a html link it adds a variable with value to the url

**HTML LINKS**

```
<a href="<?php echo c_url(); ?>&brand=hello">Brand</a><br>
<a href="<?php echo c_url(); ?>&color=red">Color</a><br>
<a href="<?php echo c_url(); ?>&size=M">Size</a><br>
<a href="<?php echo c_url(); ?>&price=12000">price</a>
```

The Problem is that when i click a button more than once it just keeps repeating the same variable and value on the url till it is filled up with it.
So what i want is that when i click a link and the value appears on the url i don't want it to appear again when i click the same link but i still want the other links to be clicked when i click it once.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the values from the query string that you do not want to duplicate. You can do this by passing the name of that parameter to your function and removing it from the `$_GET` superglobal and then building a new string.

```
function c_url($key) {
    unset($_GET[$key]);
    $queryString = http_build_query($_GET);

    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.$queryString;
}

// Pass "b" to the function to remove it from the echo'd URL
echo c_url('b') . '&b=5';
```

Output:

```
http://http://www.example.com/test.php?a=1&c=3&b=5
```

**Demo**

```
$_GET = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
];

$_SERVER = [
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/test.php',
];

function c_url($key) {
    unset($_GET[$key]);
    $queryString = http_build_query($_GET);

    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.$queryString;
}

echo c_url('b') . '&b=5';
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/PkNtH)